# Amp-fx animation on amp-list wont work until scroll

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

I have an `amp-list` with items inside that have some `amp-fx` animation. The problem is that the animation wont play until I scroll the page.

```
<amp-list
   layout="fixed-height"
   height="600"
   items="Items"
   src="https://www.api.telexiran.com/application/GetVideoHomePage">
   <template type="amp-mustache" >
        <a class="videoItem"
          href = "https://www.api.telexiran.com/{{Link}}">
               <div class="videoImage">
                   <amp-img tabindex="0" height="216" width="384" 
                   layout="responsive" amp-fx="fade-in"
                        data-margin-start="0%"
                        src="{{FullImage}}">
                   </amp-img>
         </a>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be worth opening an issue over at the [amp-html GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) as it looks like it may be a bug when the amp-fx-collection is used with amp-list. I tested it out on their playground site and got the same result - nothing loading until scroll.

Comment: I'll report it. Thanks for the try btw.